# datatable doesn't refresh after adding new record

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I have in a template two forms. One to create data and in another I have a DataTable. After a create data, it displays on DataTable after I manually refresh browser. What can I do to update/refresh DataTable after adding a new record?
In typescript code I have **ngOnInit()** witch provides data for DataTable and function **register(form: NgForm)** witch creates new data

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && register(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    here comes template for creating new data
</form>
<form>
    Here comes datatable
</form>
```

Comment: please post your code to

Answer (score 1):

As you have posted no code, I am going to take a wild guess and bet that you are adding a new record to an array that you are binding the table to.

Angular change detection will not know that you have added a new item to an array, so you need to replace the array every time you add or delete an item. This is efficient and normal